# Browser specific CSS padding for firefox field

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

I have a dropdown list in my application whereby in order to center it I must add padding-top 10px while on Mozilla Firefox but on google chrome it does not need the padding. How can I target the select list to set this browser specific. I was hoping I could have done something like the following:

```
select {
  -moz-padding-top: 10px;
  -webkit-padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Any ideas of how I could get round this? Fiddle of problem shown below, if you check this in Chrome and then Firefox, I want it so that text is always in middle

http://jsfiddle.net/uHDa6/

Comment: Padding is universal :P ... if you need it in firefox but not in chrome the problem is with another element or property please provide some code or FIDDLE

Comment: fiddle added to question

Comment: +1 for the problem. I love a challenge. But next time, describe the _problem_ (i.e. firefox aligns differently vertically and `vertical-align` does nothing), not how you are trying to hack it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Note: the first part of this answer is now obsolete, as this feature has been removed from Firefox. For the real answer, read on from "However".

---

The answer to your question is: yes, it's possible to put Mozilla-specific CSS in a stylesheet. (Not in an inline style attribute.)
In this case, you would write

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {padding-top:10px;}
}
```

which is simply the Mozilla-prefixed version of the `@document` rule, that is not recognised by other browsers.

---

However, the actual solution to the problem of the mismatched text position is to not set the height, but only the padding of the select. No hacks.

```css
style="font-size: 14px; padding: 11px 0 11px 5px;"
```

That has the desired effect in all browsers. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHDa6/15/).

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister padding alone was able to resolve I had tried this but due to the height being set was messing up so cheers.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to solve a similar problem. Firefox displays the Arial font slightly narrower than Chrome and IE do, so in order to maintain proper menu item width I had to add custom padding to Firefox. This did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be deprecated, I'm having luck using `@media(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}` with the latest versions of firefox

Comment: @sofly You are right, recent Firefoxes no longer handle `@-moz-document`. Shame. I have no idea if other hacks using prefixes will keep working for long though.