# select tag padding not working on mozilla firefox css

Tags: html, css

I tried to input a `padding: 1%;` in the `<select>` tag with `<optgroup>` in it, this works on chrome and safari, but in mozilla firefox it does not work. Is there a specific `-moz-` type? to make the padding works in mozilla ? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use mozilla specific css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser specific CSS padding for firefox field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569399/browser-specific-css-padding-for-firefox-field)

Comment: Put your minimal code to reproduce the issue or at least create a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) or [**Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone can provide you any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the mozilla specific CSS

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {padding-top:1%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your class and see if it works:

```
-moz-padding-top: 10px;
```